# How to restart my Docker container?

Tags: docker

This is what ps -a gives us

```
              NAMES
4514ea1b7b22        debian                                     "--name gallant_spen…"   9 minutes ago       Created                                                  peaceful_engelbart
df9bd2731a2b        debian                                     "--name gallant_spen…"   9 minutes ago       Created                                                  happy_hodgkin
dd5b1f1b39ec        redis                                      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   32 minutes ago      Up 31 minutes                 6379/tcp                   myred
ffd6ef9d8bd5        redis                                      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   32 minutes ago      Exited (127) 32 minutes ago                              festive_jennings
9d01d321adad        redis                                      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   33 minutes ago      Exited (0) 32 minutes ago                                agitated_shannon
eb7c13e7cdee        debian                                     "ls /data"               2 days ago          Exited (0) 9 seconds ago                                 gallant_spence
8991a31b1e38        debian                                     "ls /data"               2 days ago          Exited (0) 2 days ago                                    determined_minsky
```

I have tried in this manner

```
docker start  `docker ps -q -l` gallant_spence
```

But error ocurrs

```
Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"--name\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown
gallant_spence
Error: failed to start containers: 4514ea1b7b22
```

I am interested in data volume that has been mounted in my previous work on this container

```
 "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "bind",
            "Source": "/home/mm/code/lesson_04",
            "Destination": "/data",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": "rprivate"
        }
    ],
```

If I try

```
mm@6830s:~$ docker start -ai gallant_spence 
one_sample.py
parallel_series.py
```

Python files are added to data folder so I thought that it worked.Then I try again
docker ps

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
dd5b1f1b39ec        redis               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    6379/tcp            myred
```

Hot to fix this?

Comment: Do you understand what `docker ps -q -l` does?

Comment: @tgogos I found SO answer,probably I do not understand.

Comment: I have edited answer,start does not hel either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You `start` a stopped container with

```
docker start [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]
```

For your case, you can use:

- `docker start gallant_spence` or
- `docker start eb7c13e7cdee`

As it is shown by the `docker ps -a` result, your container is configured with this `CMD`:

```
"ls /data"
```

This means that every time you `start` your container, this command will run and the container will then exit. This is how containers work. When their primary process finishes, they exit.

---

#### About the error you get and `docker ps -q -l`:

- `-q` (from "quiet") tells the command to only print the container IDs
- `-l` (from "last") tells the command to print the latest created container

This means that the above command brings you back: `4514ea1b7b22`. If we put together all things...

your command:

```
docker start  `docker ps -q -l` gallant_spence
```

turns to:

```
docker start 4514ea1b7b22 gallant_spence
```

The fail message you get is for `4514ea1b7b22` because it doesn't have a `CMD` set properly to start. I see something like: `--name gallant_spen…`